# Get custom HTML attribute value from controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have added a custom attribute (`cust-property`) to a HTML input control,

```
<input name="myInputName" type="text" ng-model="myModel" cust-property="My Value">
```

Now I'm trying to get the value of the custom defined attribute from the validation error object list

```
for (var i in $scope.form.$error.required) {
    var elementName = $scope.form.$error.required[i].$name;
    //var customPropertyValue = $scope.form.$error.required[i].cust-property;
}
```

How can I get the custom HTML attribute value from controller?

Comment: Want to access the dom, better use a directive

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var id = $scope.form.$error.required[i].attributes['cust-property'].value;
```

But you should also get a try on directive.

Comment: It gives an error, `Cannot read property 'cust-property' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

**HTML:**

```
<input id="myInputName" name="myInputName" type="text" ng-model="myModel" cust-property="My Value" onClick="getCustom()">
```

**JS:**

```
function getCustom() {
        var mydiv = document.getElementById('myInputName');
        var custom = mydiv.getAttribute("cust-property");
        alert(custom);
        }
```